# trouble getting declared namespaces to work

Tags: html, css, xml, xhtml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to get namespaces written in an external css (two separate files actually). When I run the file on my browser it will not use the declared namespaces. I think that the file is calling the css file but its not applying the namespaced style

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<html xmlns:act="http://www.superstarmovies.com/actors" 
  xmlns:mov="http://www.superstarmovies.com/movies"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Superstar Movies: Stars of the Month</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="movies.css"  type="text/css" ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="actors.css" type="text/css" ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="superstar.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="heading"><img src="logo.gif" alt="Superstar Movies" /></div>

<div id="main">
<h1>Stars of the Month</h1>
<h3>Movies by Our Featured Stars!</h3>
<act:actors>

    <act:actor>
        <act:name>Halle Berry</act:name>
    <act:date>August 14, 1966</act:date>
    <act:birthplace>Cleveland, Ohio</act:birthplace>
          <mov:movie genre="action" star="Halle Berry">
        <mov:name>Catwoman</mov:name>
    <mov:date>(2004)</mov:date>
    <mov:length>104 minutes</mov:length>
    </mov:movie>

    <mov:movie genre="horror" star="Halle Berry">
        <mov:name>Gothika</mov:name>
    <mov:date>(2003)</mov:date>
    <mov:length>98 minutes</mov:length>
    </mov:movie>

    <mov:movie genre="drama" star="Halle Berry">
        <mov:name>Monster&apos;s Ball</mov:name>
    <mov:date>(2001)</mov:date>
    <mov:length>111 minutes</mov:length>
    </mov:movie>

    <mov:movie genre="fantasy" star="Halle Berry">
        <mov:name>X-Men</mov:name>
    <mov:date>(2000)</mov:date>
    <mov:length>104 minutes</mov:length>
    </mov:movie>

    <mov:movie genre="romance" star="Halle Berry">
        <mov:name>Jungle Fever</mov:name>
    <mov:date>(1991)</mov:date>
    <mov:length>132 minutes</mov:length>
    </mov:movie>
    </act:actor>

    <act:actor>
    <act:name>Tom Hanks</act:name>
    <act:date>July 9, 1956</act:date>
    <act:birthplace>Concord, California</act:birthplace>

<mov:movie genre="drama" star="Tom Hanks">
    <mov:name>Catch Me If You Can</mov:name>
<mov:date>(2002)</mov:date>
<mov:length>141 minutes</mov:length>
</mov:movie>

<mov:movie genre="adventure" star="Tom Hanks">
    <mov:name>Cast Away</mov:name>
<mov:date>(2000)</mov:date>
<mov:length>143 minutes</mov:length>
</mov:movie>

<mov:movie genre="action" star="Tom Hanks">
    <mov:name>Saving Private Ryan</mov:name>
<mov:date>(1998)</mov:date>
<mov:length>170 minutes</mov:length>
</mov:movie>

<mov:movie genre="adventure" star="Tom Hanks">
    <mov:name>Apollo 13</mov:name>
<mov:date>(1995)</mov:date>
<mov:length>140 minutes</mov:length>
</mov:movie>

<mov:movie genre="comedy" star="Tom Hanks">
    <mov:name>Forrest Gump</mov:name>
<mov:date>(1994)</mov:date>
<mov:length>142 minutes</mov:length>
</mov:movie>

<mov:movie genre="drama" star="Tom Hanks">
    <mov:name>Philadelphia</mov:name>
<mov:date>(1993)</mov:date>
<mov:length>125 minutes</mov:length>
</mov:movie>

<mov:movie genre="comedy" star="Tom Hanks">
    <mov:name>Big</mov:name>
<mov:date>(1988)</mov:date>
<mov:length>104 minutes</mov:length>
</mov:movie>
    </act:actor>

</act:actors>
</div>

 <address>
Superstar Movies &#183; 123 Moviestar Lane &#183; Hollywood, FL 12345
</address>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```css
 @namespace act "http://www.superstarmovies.com/actors";

act|actor        {display: block; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          margin-bottom: 20pt}

act|name, act|date   {display: block}

act|name         {font-size: 14pt; color: DarkRed; font-style: bold}

act|date, act|birthplace   {display: inline; font-style: italic; color: DarkRed}

act|birthplace         {padding-left: 0.5em}

@namespace mov "http://www.superstarmovies.com/movies";

mov|movie        {display:block; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}

mov|name, mov|date, mov|length  {display: inline}

mov|name         {font-style: bold; color:#003;}

mov|length       {font-style: italics; padding-left: 0.5em}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your XHTML:

1. Your markup is not well-formed:

   - Your XML declaration should come first, then your doctype declaration:

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     ```
   - Some of your `<link />` tags aren't closed properly, they should be:

     ```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="movies.css"  type="text/css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="actors.css" type="text/css" />
     ```
2. Your page must be served as `application/xhtml+xml` by the server. Typical servers don't know that you're serving XHTML, so they send them as `text/html` instead. Browsers won't be able to treat `text/html` files as XML, so they won't apply CSS to your custom XML elements.

   If you work with PHP, it's simply a matter of adding this to the very top of your XHTML file:

   ```php
   <?php header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml'); ?>
   ```

   Or in ASP, add this:

   ```cs
   <% Response.ContentType = "application/xhtml+xml"; %>
   ```

   You should also have an accompanying meta tag, but it's not necessary for your page to validate, and browsers ignore it anyway:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
   ```

   You can find a short history lesson on UAs treating XHTML as HTML tag soup in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8871965/106224) to better understand this.

In your CSS:

1. It's `font-weight: bold`, not `font-style: bold`.
2. It's `font-style: italic`, not `font-style: italics`.
3. Make sure that your `@namespace` statements are placed at the beginning of your stylesheets. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-namespace/#syntax):

   > Any `@namespace` rules must follow all @charset and @import rules and precede all other non-ignored at-rules and rule sets in a style sheet.

---

But with all that said, why aren't you placing your actors and movies into their own XML files, then transforming them using XSLT into familiar, **actual XHTML**?

Comment: Unless, of course, you're just doing this as an exercise, in which case there's not much that needs to be said besides highlighting the errors in your code.

Comment: Ok I make all the changes in the HTML file and what I think is happening is that what you talked about in step 4. I am not sure why its just not reading the .css at all. Yes this is for an assignment and I am not using php for this one. I think its something stupid and basic that I am missing. I edited the orginal html file to reflect changes

Comment: @Overcranked: The point about `application/xhtml+xml` is the most important. If you don't serve your XHTML with the right content type, your custom elements won't be treated correctly, and your CSS simply cannot apply. Are you using any server-side technology at all for your assignment? ASP.NET, perhaps?

Comment: No nothing special all client what you see is what Im putting out

Comment: Then you're not going to get very far with your XHTML. You'll have to take out your CSS namespaces and change your `|` to `\:` (so browsers treat them as literal characters in your element names). Then your CSS will work, but it's a hack, and your XML namespaces won't be relevant anymore.

Comment: I understand and appreciate that but I have made those changes, so I thought and am still having the same issue, so I am thinking that there is something else going on here.

Comment: There's nothing else going on here, at least not that I can see from the code you've given, so I can't help much further. Sorry about it.

Comment: Ok I applied the escape characters to all my css markup and it works. I thought that this was a work around for IE, am I confused about that?

Comment: Yes, but it's really more of a workaround for IE's inability to work with `application/xhtml+xml`, which can also apply to all browsers with regular HTML. Again, more of this in my linked answer.